# INotifyPropertyChanged vs IObservable - RxExtensions, which one for observer pattern

Tags: data-binding, architecture, system.reactive, observer-pattern

Massive re-factoring at business layer core here, and I need some help with choosing/implementing the better design pattern, and implementation.

**Question:**

1. in the ASP MVC, business layer context, when does IObservable dominate INotifyPropertyChanged
2. Which one is a better implementation for the design pattern for a genericObserableFactoryObject
3. I really like the weakEventListener because of the lower prob on memory leaks, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh199438.aspx, does this apply only to threads and thread dispatching

My due-diligence:
I understand INPC is at property level and the other is ~more at an conceptual object level, but with the LINQ it seems IObservable might be the choice. However, the simplicity and flexibility to embedded inside any object is tempting.

So, I just need *some help in understanding the design intent/purpose/motive of both, and which one would be the best reuse for an observer pattern factory.*

Also, know any place, I can get the code snippet for observer factories

Comment: What do you mean by ObserableFactoryObject and what are you trying to achieve? Knowing that it would be easier to answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, the primary usage of INPC is for clientside view data-binding (i.e. WPF, Silverlight). You can definitely use INPC in apps that are not for view binding, but you have a clunky `string` thing (PropetyName) happening here. The upside of using that is you only need one event for the whole object and the the property name is specified in the event (or empty string for the whole object should be considered changed). Alternatively you could have a `XXXPropertyChanged` event for each event

`IObservable<T>` is just an alternate implementation of the Observer pattern (ie. an alternate to .NET events). Instead of exposing an event from your class, you would expose an `IObservable<T>`. Instead of raising the event, you just `OnNext` values to the observable sequence. `IObservable<T>` also has the extra benefits of having the concept of a sequence termination via `OnError` or `OnCompleted`. So in this case, a better question would be should I use Events or `IObservable<T>`. To answer this question I would suggest favouring `IObservable<T>` unless the target audience/consumer does not want to concern themselves with learning Rx.

That was a fairly naive differentiation between the two, however I expand the concept more here http://introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/01_WhyRx.html#WhyRx

Answer (score 4):

MSDN says pretty clear.

**IObservable**

> The `IObserver<T>` and `IObservable<T>` interfaces provide a generalized mechanism for push-based notification, also known as the observer design pattern.

**INotifyPropertyChanged**

> The `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface is used to notify clients, typically binding clients, that a property value has changed.

As far as I understand, `INotifyPropertyChanged` was added long ago (for example, it had been used in WS clients and later it because most important interface in WPF binding handling).

So I assume that answer is fuzzy and clear: if you really need observer pattern, use `IObservable`.